# App keeps crashing when push notification is sent from firebase

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to send notifications to my app from firebase, as it crashes everytime i do so

It previously showed error for latest versions of the firebase_messaging plugin, so i kept it empty so that the ide will get the latest packages.

These are my dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  #firebase_auth: ^0.10.0+1
  #firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_database: ^3.0.0
  firebase_messaging:
dev_dependencies:
```

My code for the push notifications is as follows:

```
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      print("Token: $token");
    });

    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
        final notification=message['notification'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
              title: notification['title'],body: notification['body']
          ));
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
```

This the logcat summary when i run my program:

```
 Syncing files to device SM G960F...
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@b273b3b[MainActivity]
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@b273b3b[MainActivity]
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
    V/InputMethodManager(21660): Starting input: tba=com.kashyap.user_admin ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): startInputInner - Id : 0
    I/InputMethodManager(21660): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
    D/InputTransport(21660): Input channel constructed: fd=105
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@b273b3b[MainActivity]
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
    V/InputMethodManager(21660): Starting input: tba=com.kashyap.user_admin ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): startInputInner - Id : 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): ViewPostIme pointer 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): ViewPostIme pointer 1
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@b273b3b[MainActivity]
    D/InputMethodManager(21660): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
    D/SurfaceView(21660): windowStopped(true) false 7c74c04 of ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity]
    D/SurfaceView(21660): show() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.kashyap.user_admin/com.kashyap.user_admin.MainActivity@7c74c04@0[21660])/@0x81cc5ed io.flutter.view.FlutterView{7c74c04 VFE...... ........ 0,0-1440,2960}
    D/SurfaceView(21660): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #1 io.flutter.view.FlutterView{7c74c04 VFE...... ........ 0,0-1440,2960}
    W/libEGL  (21660): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72580fe010 disconnect failed
    D/SurfaceView(21660): destroy() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.kashyap.user_admin/com.kashyap.user_admin.MainActivity@7c74c04@0[21660])/@0x81cc5ed io.flutter.view.FlutterView{7c74c04 VFE...... ........ 0,0-1440,2960}
    D/SurfaceView(21660): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false 7c74c04 of ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity]
    W/libEGL  (21660): EGLNativeWindowType 0x726fef2010 disconnect failed
    D/OpenGLRenderer(21660): eglDestroySurface = 0x7266249a00, 0x726fef2000
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
    D/InputTransport(21660): Input channel destroyed: fd=105
    D/SurfaceView(21660): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false 7c74c04 of ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity]
    D/ViewRootImpl@df42dca[MainActivity](21660): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService>: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:738)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:363)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (AppComponentFactory.java:103)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:3710)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:235)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1784)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6981)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660): 
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:738)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:363)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (AppComponentFactory.java:103)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:3710)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:235)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1784)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6981)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:738)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:363)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:738)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:363)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (AppComponentFactory.java:103)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at android.app.Service androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:3710)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:235)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1784)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6981)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
    I/hyap.user_admi(21660): 
    D/AndroidRuntime(21660): Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Process: com.kashyap.user_admin, PID: 21660
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3715)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3710)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    ... 8 more
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        ... 12 more
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        ... 15 more
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.kashyap.user_admin-P6LJr-bNg8zLx2ZhadHMPA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
    E/AndroidRuntime(21660):        ... 15 more
    I/Process (21660): Sending signal. PID: 21660 SIG: 9
    Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub issue/comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23545#issuecomment-434041145) suggests you need to pay very close attention to the plugin versions you are using. This means you'll also have to keep the platform specific dependencies updated as well ([this for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)).

From the Firebase docs:

```
app/build.gradle:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

Comment: The error now changed, and no matter what i do it remains the same:
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You'll have to look at all the plugins that also require specific lib versions to see what is compatible and update pubspec and the gradle files accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The code started working when i added lates firebase core plugin and enabled androidx along with changing the gradle version from 5.1.1 to 4.10.2 and the gradle dependency in project level build.gradle to

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

instead of:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```